# Issue with sorting a json array in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a ruby expression that builds a json array as follows

```
<%= raw((Object.listA | Object.listB).map { |s| {s.id.to_s => s.name} }.reduce(Hash.new, :merge).to_json)%>
```

In the expression above, Object is an ActiveRecord which has 2 attributes called listA and listB. Each one of these lists is a list of objects with an id and name. I want to merge these 2 lists and then sort the final list by name. I have tried doing the following but I'm unable to get a sorted list by name.

```
<%= raw((Object.listA | Object.listB).sort_by{ |s| s.name}.map { |s| {s.id.to_s => s.name} }.reduce(Hash.new, :merge).to_json)%>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
Object.listA.merge(Object.listB)
            .sort_by(&:name)
            .map { |o| { o.id.to_s => o.name } }
            .to_json
```

I am not sure what you try to achieve with the `reduce(Hash.new, :merge)` method call. Furthermore, I suggest following Ruby naming conventions (variables and method name in underscore instead of camelcase) and moving complex method chains like these from the view into the model or a helper.